# "County" showing up as top keyword due to drop down menu. Should I take steps to fix?

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

We have a database of dealers by state and county. It gets put into a dropdown form using `<option>`

Currently it shows :

`Select County:
   First County
   Second County`

So on as a drop down. As a result Google Webmaster Tools is showing the top content keyword as County, by a long margin.

All of the other keywords look fairly accurate. Will having County at the top have negative impact on search results or since the others are alright it won't make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword count in webmaster tools is just a report of word frequency found on your site, it doesn't mean you will or wont rank for those terms.

*Q: Why do my Webmaster Tools stats show common phrases such as "buy now" that are not directly related to my site?
A: While some common words and phrases are filtered by Webmaster Tools, there may be some that you use which are not. Having these words or phrases listed in your Webmaster Tools account does not mean that our algorithms will view your site as being only relevant for those keywords. While Webmaster Tools mostly counts the occurences of words on your site, our web-search algorithms use well over 200 other factors for crawling, indexing and ranking. **In other words: don't worry if you see keywords like this listed in your Webmaster Tools account**.* 
https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--webmaster-tools#strange-words2

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, on one of my sites I rank for the word *found*. So you rank for *county*?! While it is not the end of the world, I would change the drop down so that the *options* do not have the word county. I dropped the word *found* and it will begin shaking out in my next deployment. The reason why I recommend dropping the usage of the word county is that it dilutes your keyword prowess. While it is not a big deal, it is something you want to fix... that is unless you want to rank for the word county. It happens to all of us from time to time.